# Load all classes in all JARs to classpath

Tags: java, cmd, jar, classpath, executable-jar

I have a folder `libs` that contains several JARs, and I have an application (let's say `MyTest.jar`) that uses some classes from those libs. What I need is to run `MyTest.jar` with a kind of `-cp` (`-classpath`) argument that will add all JARs in folder `libs` to classpath fully.

I have already tried `java -cp E:\libs -jar MyTest.jar`. However, this doesn't seem to load the libraries at all, as can be seen in this error I get (which states it can't find one of library classes `me.darksidecode.simpleconfigs.Config`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/darksidecode/simpleconfigs/Config
        at me.darksidecode.KekGUI.<init>(KekGUI.java:31)
        at me.darksidecode.KekGUI.main(KekGUI.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.darksidecode.simpleconfigs.Config
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

The line where the exception is thrown is:

```
Config testcfg = new Config("hello = world");
```

Where `Config` (`me.darksidecode.simpleconfigs.Config`) is a class of the `SimpleConfigs.jar` library, which **is present** in my `libs` (`E:\libs`) folder and **is valid**.

To no avail I have also tried specifying one of libraries (`SimpleConfigs.jar`) explicitly: `java -cp E:\libs\SimpleConfigs.jar -jar MyTest.jar`. Same error happens.

How can I get this to work?

**EDIT:** it appears that I have to specify classpath in the `MyTest.jar`'s MANIFEST.MF file. And here I've got a new problem: I can only specify exact JAR name in `Class-Path`, like this:

```
Class-Path: /E:/libs/SimpleConfigs.jar
```

It works like that. But when I try to specify the whole directory:

```
Class-Path: /E:/libs/
```

It starts throwing the aforementioned error (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`) again.

Comment: @SeverityOne Thanks, though now I'm having a different problem. Updated my post.

Comment: If your problem was solved, you should either write in an answer or delete the post. If you have a new question you should start a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java documentation states

> -jar
>
> Executes a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. For this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line in the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class with the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your application's starting point.
>
> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored`.

One workaround is to append MyTest.jar to the classpath (-cp) and specify the main class in the MyTest.jar as argument to java

```
java -cp Mytest.jar;E:\libs\* me.darksidecode.KekGUI
```